# Size of the Variable Labels in RGL 3DPlot

Tags: rgl

I'm using RGL to make a three-dimensional scatterplot for three continuous variables. I want to add the labels of country abbreviations to the scatterplot, which works, but the size of the labels is too big. Is there a possibility of making them smaller?

This is my code:

```
reg2008=read.spss("C:/Users/mderoeck/Documents/R/3D/Year/Year2008.sav",to.data.frame=TRUE, use.value.labels=TRUE) 
install.packages("rgl")
require("rgl")
plot3d(reg2008$comp,reg2008$instconst,reg2008$cpl, xlab = "Competition", ylab="Institutional Constraints", zlab = "Civil Rights and Political Liberties", size = 1)
text3d(x=reg2008$comp, y=reg2008$instconst, z=reg2008$cpl, texts=reg2008$stateabb, adj = 0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using freeType fonts, but bitmap fonts, size cannot be changed. Bitmap fonts are defined in pixels. freeType is vector graphics. freeType is third party software and needs to be installed outside R(if you do not already have it).

code below explains

```
#some data
df.pos = data.frame(runif(10),runif(10),runif(10))

#you cannot change text size like this
par3d(useFreeType=FALSE)
plot3d(df.pos)
text3d(df.pos,text=1:10,add=T,cex=8)


#install third party FreeType for vector texts
#and now you can change font size
par3d(useFreeType=TRUE)
plot3d(df.pos)
text3d(df.pos,text=paste("     ",1:10),add=T,cex=0.4,justify="left")
```

paste("     ") is to place the label left of the point no matter scaling